# Save my mouse event drawing for future modification

Tags: c#, winforms, save, drawing

I have used (visual studio, windows form, c#) to create some drawings.

My goal is to add save button to save the drawing as it is and when I open the saved file in future I can continue my old work...

What happen now is every time I open visual studio I have to redraw every thing .

Comment: You can put all your drawing in array dan save this array in a file. Next time, you need only to load this file and redraw it again.

Comment: I am using Bitmap and rectangle to draw images and circles, I don't know how to save them as array :(

Comment: That was only an idea. You can use also object structure and serialize it to a file, for example using BinaryFormatter.

Comment: do you have an example to do that ? I am still consider myself a beginner in c#

Comment: You need to decide if you want to save the Bitam in a file or the data. The data need to be collected in a List<T> of a helpful class. Make sure to make it serializable so you can easily save and load it. For a full example this is too broad. To see a discussion of the data collection see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714411/update-a-drawing-without-deleting-the-previous-one/28716887?s=6|0.1765#28716887)

Answer (score 1):

The first task is collecting the data you draw in a `List<T>`. 
For code on how to collect them see (all) [my comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280801/smoother-graphics-than-smoothingmode-antialias#38280801) or Reza's answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296729/undoing-using-a-list-to-redraw#38296729)

Here is an example to save & load simple `PointF` lists you can use to draw curves:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

// all drawn curve points are collected here:
List<List<PointF>> curves = new List<List<PointF>>();



private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    XmlSerializer xmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<List<PointF>>));
    using (Stream writer = new FileStream(yourDrawingFileName, FileMode.Create))
    {
        xmls.Serialize(writer, curves);
        writer.Close();
    }
}

private void LoadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (File.Exists(yourDrawingFileName))
    {

        XmlSerializer xmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<List<PointF>>));
        using (Stream reader = new FileStream(yourDrawingFileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var curves_ = xmls.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.Close();
            curves = (List<List<PointF>>) curves_;
            Console.Write(curves.Count + " curves loaded.");
        }
    }
    yourPanelOrPictureBoxOrForm.Invalidate;
}
```

If you want to save a more complex class of drawing actions replace `PointF` by `yourClass`. Make sure the class is serializable! (`Points` are fine, `ints` and `strings` of course as well; `Colors` need a little help..)

For hints on how to design a more complex draw action class see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714411/update-a-drawing-without-deleting-the-previous-one/28716887?s=6|0.1765#28716887)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try and let you know

Comment: Sure, take your time and do ask when you run into probelms..!