# How to see if the cursor is over an ellipse

Tags: c#, windows, forms, winforms, ellipse

I'm currently programming a Windows Form Application using Visual Studio 2015. The program "spawns" 24 circles at the start which will then disappear, one by one, as the user clicks the different circles. The problem is that I don't know how to check if the cursor is over an ellipse when the user clicks.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to store your ellipse coordinates for example in a `List<Rectangle>` or a `List<GraphicsPath>` and use `GraphicsPath.IsVisible` method to perform hit test . Also you can create an `Ellipse` class and encapsulate drawing and hit testing in that class. Take a look at this example: [How can I treat the circle as a control after drawing it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38345828/how-can-i-treat-the-circle-as-a-control-after-drawing-it)

Comment: While a circle is an ellipse, an ellipse is not necessarily a circle.  So are you creating circles or ellipses?

Comment: @SamAxe I'm creating circles with the "FillEllipse" command, giving them the same value in height and width.

Comment: @RezaAghaei According to Visual Studio, the `GraphicsPath` type doesn't exist. :(

Comment: @VÄLFÄRD, according to Microsoft's [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath(v=vs.110).aspx), it does.

Comment: It's [`System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath(v=vs.110).aspx). You can use its full name or add `using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;`

Comment: @RezaAghaei Ah, thanks!

Comment: `GraphicsPath`, in my experience, is incredibly slow.

Comment: _GraphicsPath, in my experience, is incredibly slow_ Nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

If you store the center points and the radius<sup>1</sup> then you can check the [distance between the clicked point and all the centers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem).  If the distance is less than the radius then you have a click within the circle bounds.

If you need to keep track of overlapping circles and only remove a the one on "top", then you need to store a z component with your point and radius data as well.

```
public class Circle {
    public int X {get; set;}  
    public int Y {get; set;}
    public int Z {get; set;}

    public int Radius {get; set;}
}
```

Store your data in a `List<Circle>`.  Then you can easily extend the Circle class with methods like `public bool Contains(int x, int y) { ... }`, which makes writing the above algorithm as a LINQ query very easy.

Comment: Take a look at `Cricle` class at the end of linked post, you will find it really useful.