# how to select drawn shapes like circle or rectangle in panel with mouse in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent, draw, shapes

I'm trying to make a **minipaint** application which has three buttons(rectangle, circle and line). I'm having problem with selecting and moving shapes with mouse. For example I have this rectangle class which inherits color, thickness from shape:

```
class rectangle : shape
{
  public int length { get; set; }
  public int width { get; set; }

  public override void Draw(Graphics g)
  {
    g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(color), new Rectangle(startx, starty, width,length));
   }
 }
```

Now, I want my panel1_MouseDown to select a rectangle in my panel whenever I click on any part of rectangle.
All drawn shapes are added to a list named  lstShapsOnForm and drawable is an abstract class that has abstract method of draw and property x y.

```
abstract class Drawable
{
  public int x { get; set; }
  public int y { get; set; }
  public abstract void draw(Graphics g);
 }

 private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
    foreach (Drawable o in lstShapsOnForm)
    {
       if (e.Location.X >= o.x || e.Location.X < o.x)
        propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = o;       
    }
 }
```

How should I make this work?

Comment: Take a look at [How can I treat the circle as a control after drawing it? - Moving and selecting shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38345828/3110834)  or this post [How to drag and move shapes in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38747027/3110834).

Answer (score 0):

Simplest thing is to make it the responsibility of the shape to know if they have been clicked in, so add a IsInside method eg:

```
abstract class Drawable
{
  public int x { get; set; }
  public int y { get; set; }
  public abstract void draw(Graphics g);
  public abstract bool IsInside(int x, int y);
}
```

Then to test:

```
var shapeHit = lstShapsOnForm.FirstOrDefault(s => s.IsInside(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y));    
if (shapeHit != null)
  propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = shapeHit;
```

For the rectangle, assuming you know the width and height (you should if you drew it), and assuming that the x and y properties are the top left corner, then it would be somehting like this:

```
public override bool IsInside(int mouseX, int mouseY) 
{
    return 
        mouseX >= x && 
        mouseX <= x + width &&
        mouseY >= y &&
        mouseY <= y + height;
}
```

For the circle and line ..... I suggest you google 'how to determine if x/y point is inside circle / on line'. It will involve testing using the radius (for the circle) and the 2 line points (for the line)

Comment: But i don't know how to find out  e.location is inside of shape or not

Comment: Which one - rectangle, circle, line - or all of them?

Comment: All of them .any shape drawn on panel.

Comment: ah ok - well I added idea for the easy one (the rectangle) - I would have to google the others  so I won't do them