# Preserving pen size?

Tags: c#, graphics

So I'm making a paint app, and I'm wondering how I can preserve the thickness of lines I draw. So my app uses a list of a list of points of all lines drawn, and draws them all again every time a new line is drawn by the user. Now I have one problem, when I change the pen size, the size of ALL the lines change, as they're all getting redrawn.

My code:

```
        //Create new pen
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, penSize);
        //Set linecaps for start and end to round
        p.StartCap = LineCap.Round;
        p.EndCap = LineCap.Round;
        //Turn on AntiAlias
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        //For each list of line coords, draw all lines
        foreach (List<Point> lstP in previousPoints)
        { 
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, lstP[0], lstP[1]);
        }
        p.Dispose();
```

I know one can use Pen.Width() to change the pen size during the loop but how can I preserve line widths?

Comment: You may want to study [this post about a DrawAction class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714411/update-a-drawing-without-deleting-the-previous-one/28716887?s=6|0.1736#28716887)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `List<List<Point>>`, write a class that has a `List<Point>` and a pen width, and use a list of that. We'll throw in color as well, but you can omit that.

```
public class MyPointList {
    public List<Point> Points { get; set; }
    public float PenWidth { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
}
```

Make previousPoints a list of those:

```
private List<MyPointList> previousPoints;
```

And loop through:

```
foreach (MyPointList lstP in previousPoints) {
    using (var p = new Pen(lstP.Color, lstP.PenWidth)) {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, lstP.Points[0], lstP.Points[1]);
    }
}
```

The `using` block disposes the pens.

As Kyle notes in comments, you could give `MyPointList` a method that does the drawing, too.

In fact, you could write a base class with an abstract or virtual `Draw(Graphics g)` method:

```
public abstract class MyDrawingThing {
    public abstract void Draw(Graphics g);
}

public class MyPointList : MyDrawingThing {
    public List<Point> Points { get; set; }
    public float PenWidth { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }

    public override void Draw(Graphics g) {
        using (var p = new Pen(Color, PenWidth)) {
            g.DrawLine(p, Points[0], Points[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

...and use like so:

```
private List<MyDrawingThing> previousPoints;

foreach (MyDrawingThing thing in previousPoints) {
    thing.Draw(e.Graphics);
}
```

Write a dozen different subclasses that draw circles, arcs, lolcats, whatever.

Comment: You're a genius! Thanks.

Comment: In fact, you could even add a `Draw` method to this custom class that handles drawing the line with the correct `Pen`.

Comment: @Kyle Thanks, I added that.